# What is AJAX HeartBeat and what is the difference between it and setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, setinterval, heartbeat

I want to know what is exactly AJAX heartbeat pattern and what is the difference between it and jquery setInterval

Because im making an AJAX chat and I don't want to pull the data every 15 seconds I want to make a connection to the server to avoid delay is that what called heartbeat  ?
Also I want a good tutorial to make this or any suggestion from you

Note: I have completed the implementation with setInterval but I saw that heartbeat is better way to avoid delay

Comment: Afaik this is a design pattern and not a _function_. You keep sending requests to the server, so the server knows the user/browser is still present. - First hits on google...

Comment: In my question in the first line i asked what is AJAX heartbeat pattern 
and i said its pattern 
I am hitting google since two days and I came here because here i can see experts that already done this before and can give me the concept better not punishing me for my question 
anyway thank you for your help I will appreciate reading the question first and consider that I will not ask here until i am out of solutions

Comment: It's a deisgn pattern and not a function. You knew that, ok. I downvoted this question, because I don't see the research effort in it since the first result on google explain the pattern. - I may decided to harsh. Fixed it. Please state the next time your research effort more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heartbeat is a design pattern, this means it's a way of coding solutions.

Here a technique is meant, where you keep sending requests to the server, so the server knows the user/browser is still present. There are several use-cases for this pattern, for example to prevent timeouts of sessions etc.

You cannot really compare a design pattern to a function, because `setInterval` could be used to implement this pattern. You would keep sending request in a specified interval.

I don't have a tutorial at hand, but the first hits on google already contain some examples.

Comment: What you want as an alternative is something like a push notification.

Comment: Thank @Smamatti for this answer 
I tried google but what i wanted is more info from experts like you please if you found such tutorial post it here

Comment: This is the first hit on Google for heartbeat ajax.

Comment: @NickNo Be more creative when searching and do not search for 'ajax heartbeat' only. Try adding 'example' or 'tutorial' and you will find sample codes.